# db_update query does not work properly

Tags: database

I work with views bulk operations and I wanna change status of selected items in a view. I applied db_update query, but something went wrong. I was debugging my code following:

```
  $status=$context['status'];


foreach($context['rows'] as $order) {

    db_update('orders')
        ->fields(array(
            'status' => $status
        ))
        ->condition('oid',$order->oid,'=')
        ->execute();
}



foreach($context['rows'] as $order) {
    $result = db_select('orders','status')
        ->fields('status')
        ->condition('oid',$order->oid)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
    if($result) {
        drupal_set_message($result['status']);
        drupal_set_message($result['oid']);
    }
}
```

So first is db_update and after that I did db_select and printed it out.The result of this db_select behaves like status would be updated. But in the node is status still the same. Also in database it stayed unchanged. I have no idea what's wrong. It behaves like it was updated and then immediately got back.I would be very helpful for any help. Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: My first inclination is that this is a caching issue. Other possibilities: Is the node actually stored in the `orders` table? Do you do the appropriate updates for the nodes table as well? Is this in an incomplete transaction? (db_transaction) Have you checked the return value of `execute()` to see if it is returning the right number of rows? Without a full description of what the variable `$context` and the table `orders` contains, it is hard to give any better answer.

Comment: No. The node is not stored in orders table. I update just order's field status. The return value of execute() is always 1 for every update I do in a foreach loop. Context variabe is fine. I dumped all variables and they are correct. If they wouldn's the select query does not work properly.

Comment: If I look into database, I can see via date of last change, that these rows I wanted to update were changed after my query is executed.

Comment: If the rows were updated, but new info is not displayed, then it has to be a caching issue.

If they were updated and then changed back, then you have something else overriding your changes.